# How do I pass the value of an array to another class?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I'm trying to pass in an array value of colors that is in another class to FunFactsActivity in Android Studio. Right now, I'm getting an error 
`setBackgroundColor(int) in View cannot be applied to (java.lang.String).`
`relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(mColorWheel.mColors[currentColor]);`

From what I understand, I can't pass in an int into it since its a String, but I'm just trying to make the colors i already have in that array fade every few seconds/intervals to the relativeLayout background in a thread and can't get it right. What am I doing wrong?

**FunFactsActivity.java**

```
// update background color of relativeLayout every few seconds.
private void updateColor()
{
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    int color = mColorWheel.getColor();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            if (currentColor > mColorWheel.mColors.length - 1)
            {
                currentColor = 0;

            }
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(mColorWheel.mColors[currentColor]);

            currentColor++;

        }// end of run
    });

}
```

**ColorWheel.java**

```
public class ColorWheel {

    // Member variable (properties about the object)
    public String[] mColors = {
            "#39add1",
            "#3079ab",
            "#c25975",
            "#e15258",
            "#f9845b",
            "#838cc7",
            "#7d669e",
            "#53bbb4",
            "#e0ab18",
            "#637a91",
            "#f092b0",
            "#b7c0c7",
            "#FAEBD7",
            "#00FFFF",
            "#7FFFD4",
            "#0000FF",
            "#8A2BE2",
            "#A52A2A",
            "#DEB887",
            "#5F9EA0",
            "#7FFF00",
            "#D2691E",
            "#6495ED",
            "#DC143C",
            "#B8860B",
            "#A9A9A9",
            "#006400",
            "#FF8C00",
            "#8B0000",
            "#FFD700",
            "#FF69B4",
            "#4B0082",
            "#F08080",
            "#90EE90",
            "#87CEFA",
            "#FF4500",
            "#DA70D6",
            "#FA8072",
            "#9ACD32",
            "#00FF7F",
            "#4682B4",
    };

    // Method (abilities: things the object can do)
    public int getColor(){

        String color = "";
        // Randomly select a fact
        Random randomGenerator = new Random(); // Construct a new Random number generator
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mColors.length);

        color = mColors[randomNumber];
        int colorAsInt = Color.parseColor(color);

        return colorAsInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: simple on FunFactsActivity.java create a object of class ColorWheel.
like
`ColorWheel cw = new ColorWheel()`

and access the array like 

`cw.mColors[i];`

Comment: Why don't you just change the string array of `mColors` to an int array. So as an example `#39add1` would become `0x39add1`, etc.

Comment: Try `relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mColorWheel.mColors[currentColor]));`

Comment: @Universe I'm getting Variable 'mColors' is from a inner class and needs to be declared final.

Comment: @DanielNugent Tried this and says it cannot be resolved.

Comment: @BenyamEphrem Because I would then have to change everything else that is associated with the colors and don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ColorWheel` class is already calling `Color.parseColor` in `getColor` function.
Just use the function as it is getting a random color already.

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(mColorWheel.getColor());
```

or if you want to use the mColors array:

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mColorWheel.mColors[currentColor]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't go through the whole code, but when setting the color in Android, you either:

- provide an `int` which is a reference to the color id, for example: `R.color.my_red`
- provide a `Color` object. In your case if you want to convert hex value to a `Color`, call `Color.parseColor("#000000")`